# create a dynamic combobox in asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am binding controls on gridview by using button click as follows. i have bound controls like label and textboxes. but i couldnt bind dropdown which has "skin id"(because skin id is not acceptable in javascript). so i change my mind and would bind them through a function. but i couldn't call the function on "onload" event of dropdown. For your concern, I posted my code below.

```
 var Positions = xml.find("Table");
 var row = $("[id*=gridview] tr:last");
 $("[id*=gridview] tr").not($("[id*=gridview] tr:first-child")).remove();
 $.each(Positions, function () {
 $("td", row).eq(0).html('<div><span id="lbltype">'+Position.find("type").text()+'<span/></div><div style="display:none;" ><select id="gddltype" onload="ddlTypeLoad(this);"></select></div>'); // here onload is the only problem
 });

function ddlTypeLoad(ctrl)
{
  var values=["Export","Import","Loan"];
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
  {
      var ddloption=new Option(values[i],values[i]);
      ctrl.options.add(ddloption);
  }
}
```

I think we can't give onload event to dropdown on client side. if it is please give me an alternate solution.

Also i would like to know the alternate code of

```
<asp:dropdownlist SelectedValue="&&&&">
```

in html. Thanks